# File security System in java?

Tags: java, file, security, encryption

i'm new to java world.I have a idea about file secure system.When i add
 a file to the application it will encrypt and store a folder in the 
 installation path.If i need to see the file ,i need to login with my 
 username and password and the file will automatically decrypted to another folder.
i think i can encrypt file using `AES or DES`
 but anyone can't access these folder from outside.
My problem is can i do all these things using java,If i can give me some suggestions
please???

Comment: *"If i can give me some suggestions"* You may give yourself suggestions. *"can i do all these things using java"* As far as I understood your question, yes

Comment: Yes, you can encrypt and decrypt files using Java. And now it is your turn: do some research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to encrypt an aspect of the file you may want to gather it's bytes in an array*, That can either be done using the class Files from java or a stream to do it manually. For now lets say you got the byte array obtained using `Files.readAllBytes(Path file);`
So now you use whatever encryption you want for these bytes.
Then you write them to a file using a stream.

Thats about it for the encryption.

> *The flaw of the code above is that it loads the byte array straight on memory. Thats fine if the file is a few KB but otherwise it is
> verry resource consuming and may lead to an "OutOfMemoryException". To
> avoid this you may want to have 2 streams, one to read and another to
> write, as you read a byte or a chunk of bytes from the file, you
> encrypt it/them and you use the output stream to write it to another
> file.

The login is very simple to handle (Depending on the aproach) both for console and GUI aplications. If username and password are variables in the aplication and you simply check if the input matches them, thats fine but if you want active registrations and so on you need file(s) to hold theese details. In any case the username and password can be obtained by decompiling your program or deserialising the serialised data.

So to answer the last part of your question, yes you can do it with java :- )

## JavaRules!

Comment: Thanks a lot man.I got that , but how to secure a folder?

Comment: Anytime :D
Although you can always save the file bytes into one file where they are somehow seperated one from the other and essentially have an encrypted file that contains other files :3 (im not good at this cuz i havent experimented with it D:)
Otherwise use FileLock class from java ([link]http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html[/link]) :- ) Still i have no experience with it and therefore i cant evaluate how safe it is...
If there is any other way i can help let me know :)

Comment: Can i store the encrypted file in a database?i think it's safe

Comment: Yes ofcaurse you can :D 
I am not sure how safe it would be since not everyone has a DB server and even if you use SQL lite for instance to use Local filesystem for the DB file, it is extremely simple for someone to download a database file explorer and open up your DB.
File to DB: http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/insert-file-data-into-mysql-database-using-jdbc

Oh, i forgot, in a previous project of mine, in order to make a file "encrypted" (Litle i knew) i inverted its bytes from lets say 10, 4,42...44,87 to87,44...,42,4,10 and that corrupted the file but it could easily be undone :D

Comment: Ty mate :D
And if you have any other question let me (or us) know!

Comment: Hey I have another problem: How install my exe with database to another computer

Comment: I didnt get that :- ( 
Do you have an executable file pausing as an installer of your aplication and you want to install it on another pc?

Comment: I ave done my project and i created a exe using exe4j,but how to connect the exe with my database.if use my exe in another pc i think i need to install the database too?

Comment: Hmm i have no idea :- ( i only used exe format for a java aplication once and ever since i dont like it :- (